# Explanation of the mod result of long

Tags: python, python-2.7

Why is 600851475143 % 3 == 2L and not 0?

For small integers the mod works correctly, however this is not the case for a long. How do I make the mod work similar to integers?

Comment: Why would it be `0`?

Comment: I'm guessing the OP sees the 3 at the end...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works correctly. It should not be zero.

The `%` (modulo) operator yields the remainder from the division of the first argument by the second.

```
600851475143 % 3 = 2
```

Because:

```
600851475143 / 3 = 200283825047.67
```

It still works perfectly fine on large numbers, eg.

```
600851475144 % 3 = 0
```

Here's the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html)

Comment: oh... when i run 600851475143 / 3, I get 200283825047. And that is why I thought it does not work. If I say float(600851475143 / 3), I get scientific notation, and I still cant see whether there is a remainder: 2.00283825047e+11

Comment: a=float(600851475143/3), even when I assign a variable to the result. In the variable explorer it appears as if though there is no remainder: 200283825047.0

Comment: That's because division between two ints in python 2 is integer division. Want to check? Try `1/2` You will get `0`, not `0.5`

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal: Python 2 division with two integers uses floor division. Use `600851475143 / 3.0` (force one of the arguments to be a float) or use `from __future__ import division` to switch to a consistent always-float-division behaviour (and use `//` for floor division).

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal: What Martijn said. Doing `a=float(600851475143/3)` doesn't help, since you convert to `float` _after_ doing the integer division. But try Martijn's suggestions, or this modification of your code: `float(600851475143)/3`